# How do you write a springboot class for a mongodb document with nested properties?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a json document

```
{
 description:"desc", 
 user:{name:"Name", email:"email"}, 
 properties:[
      {name:"propName1",val:"propValue1"},
      {name:"propName2",val:"propValue2"}
      ]
}
```

I defined the class in spring framework:

```
@Document(collection = "mydocuments")
public class MyDocument extends BaseDocument {
    private String description;
    ....?
}
```

How do I define user and properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write two classes and create the instance inside the MyDocument class.

```
class User{
    String name;
    String email;
    
    // Constructors getters and setters
}

class Property{
    String name;
    String val;
    
    // Constructors getters and setters
}

@Document(collection = "mydocuments")
public class MyDocument extends BaseDocument {
    private String description;
    private User user;
    private List<Property> properties;
}
```